# how to redirect my /old/folder to /newfolder in htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I need to redirect an URL of my website. In fact, how to redirect my `/old/folder` to `/newfolder` in htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^//old/folder. https://website.com/newFolder/
```

I used this code :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^//old/folder https://website.com/newFolder/
```

It shows an error 404!

Comment: Why a double slash at the start of the path? And why even RedirectMatch, when what you want to redirect is a _static_ path to begin with? Redirect is enough for that, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect any file.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old/folder/(.*)$ https://website.com/newFolder/$1
```